# Comparing between 2 rows and highlighting the difference

Tags: excel, vba, compare

Would need some help to compare two rows in Excel and highlight difference.

I have this code:

```
With ActiveSheet

    Last_Column = .Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column

    For lLoop = 1 To Last_Column
        If .Cells(1, lLoop).VALUE <> .Cells(2, lLoop).VALUE Then 
           .Cells(1, lLoop).Interior.ColorIndex = 4             
        End If    
    Next

End With
```

But it compares only the first two rows. Could you help me compare between rows(1&2,3&4,5&6 etc) till the end of the sheet and highlight the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below, explanation inside the code comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CompareRows()

Dim i As Long, Col As Long
Dim LastRow As Long, Last_Column As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet1") '<-- modify to your sheet's name (don't rely on ActiveSheet)
    ' get last row
    LastRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    ' first add a loop of rows, step every 2
    For i = 1 To LastRow Step 2
        Last_Column = .Cells(i, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column  ' get last column in current row

        ' loop through columns
        For Col = 1 To Last_Column
            If .Cells(i, Col).Value <> .Cells(i + 1, Col).Value Then
                .Cells(i, Col).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            End If
        Next Col            
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What if some rows are hidden and need to be skipped? OR what if some columns are hidden? Bottom line: There is no end of what ifs, we should stick to what OP states in the original requirement and should not try to impose our own what if hypothetical analysis.

Comment: @sktneer yes, that's true, but this scenario is too obvious to let go (at least for me)

Comment: Worked great.Thanks a ton!

Comment: Hey Update-I get a type mismatch on data more than 200 rows(only 5 columns).How do i resolve that.

Comment: @Sona123  count of rows shouldn't matter, maybe you have invalid data in one of the added rows

Answer (score 0):

The code you have will only work for the rows 1 and 2 as you have hard coded them in the code and also you are looping through columns not looping through rows.

You need two loops, one looping through rows and another looping through columns.

Give this a try...

```
Sub CompareRows()
Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long
LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
LastColumn = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

For i = 1 To LastRow Step 2
    For j = 1 To LastColumn
        If Cells(i, j) <> Cells(i + 1, j) Then Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```